# Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace Cannot install remote marketplace locations:

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace
Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Cannot complete request to https://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

eclipse:
Version: 2022-12 (4.26.0)
Build id: 20221201-1913

JDK 11.0.9

Solution, and from where we can get this certification and where to install.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ See if that link helps any.

Comment: 2022-12 must be run with Java 17.

Comment: Although the core of Eclipse 2022-12 will run with Java 11 some individual plug-ins require Java 17. Many of the Eclipse downloads include a built-in Java 17.